# Weird Black Mark shows up On animation

Tags: rendering

[image: Weird issue] Hello, I am completely new to 3D modelling and I am being taught by a friend, However, When I was rendering a logo, I found this!

It is a black mark that seems to change depending on which part of the animation I am looking at

Comment: It looks like a repeated spotlight, interesting.

Comment: How can I solve the "repeated spotlight problem"? I have only one light source in my blender workspace.

Comment: Actually, I just checked, I have an object known as "sun" which is a light object AND the light, thanks for helping me, its all fixed now!